# How to change interior.color in excel, across multiple columns using a row variable

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, vba

I'm trying to highlight a row that's assigned to "RowNum"  I want to highlight Columns A through O. I've tried the things below, But receive syntax errors on each.

```
sh1.Cells(RowNum, 15).Interior.Color = RGB(127, 187, 199)
sh1.Range("A" & RowNum : "O" & RowNum).interior.color = rgb (127,187,199)
```

In the past, I've used this to highlight a set range or individual cells.

```
sh1.Range("W1:X1").Interior.Color = RGB(252, 213, 180)
```

I know I've done this in the past, either that or I am suffering a concussion.

Comment: "But neither are working correctly" isn't a good description, what is the issue exactly?  Have you tried recording a similar macro, does it work?

Comment: I receive syntax errors on both lines.(thanks for pointing that out, making edit now) The macro recorder won't work because I am trying to use a variable for the row number.

Comment: We need more information if you want us to help.  Please post the syntax you have tried (we have this) and directly below it please post what the error you receive is.  From the limited information in your post, one would think you googled to find the code snippets above and are attempting to use SO as a code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

If `sh1.Range("A" & RowNum : "O" & RowNum).interior.color = rgb (127,187,199)` is the actual line from your macro, you have a typo

`sh1.Range("A" & RowNum : "O" & RowNum)` should be `sh1.Range("A" & RowNum & ":" & "O" & RowNum)`

The colon `:` needs to be concatenated like everything else, since it's part of the range string